# Converting Unix timestamp to Locale timezone

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

All,

How can I convert to a unix timestamp to date and time in local timezone. For timestamp = 1303374724716, the `date ('r', $timestamp)` function of PHP gives me `Sun, 16 May 2032 22:11:37 +0000` whereas the [epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) CORRECTLY converts to
`GMT: Thu, 21 Apr 2011 08:32:04 GMT

Your timezone: Thu Apr 21 2011 04:32:04 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

I have seen the php.ini file and the default timezone is UTC. I don't understand why the value doesn't even match the GMT/UTC time. Can anyone please help me convert to my local timezone i.e. New_York.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the timestamp you are given is in milliseconds.

Do:

```
$timestamp = floor(1303374724716/1000);
```

And everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The docs say:

> timestamp is optional and defaults to the value of time().

If you run

```
print time();
```

you will get a number like `1304640077`.

Note that it is 1000 times smaller than the number you are trying to pass it.

In other words, you should be passing it a value in seconds, not milliseconds.

To set the time zone, use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), e.g.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

or set [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) in the php.ini file.